# Duvida sobre Group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

usando o SQL Server

fiz o seguinte select para selecionar produtos comprados pelos clientes:

```
select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE, CLIENTE.NOME  
  from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido
  where PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO=ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO AND CLIENTE.IDCLIENTE = PEDIDO.IDCLIENTE
  order by ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE desc
```

resultado :

IDPEDIDO QUANTIDADE NOME

5 3 Adrina Domingues

1 1 Edivaldo Santana

2 1 José Antonio

3 1 Hugo Batista

3 1 Hugo Batista

4 1 Cristina Oliveira

1 1 Edivaldo Santana

2 1 José Antonio

agora pretendo somar os itens da quantidade dependendo do id pedido, porem esta dando erro.

```
select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, sum (ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE), CLIENTE.NOME  from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido

      where PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO=ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO AND CLIENTE.IDCLIENTE = PEDIDO.IDCLIENTE

      group by ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO

      order by ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE desc --FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

msg de erro :

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Não tem sentido esta cláusula ORDER BY com o GROUP BY / SUM especificado.

Comment: Caso queira ordenar por `sum (ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE)` você pode utilizar, para esta query, o número 2 (o segundo campo da lista de seleção). Também sua cláusula ORDER BY deveria especificar ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO e CLIENTE.NOME para fazer sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir a expressão de agrupamento na cláusula SELECT.

É necessário utilizar uma delas: SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, etc ... neste seu contexto o SUM

Importante ficar atento que, para utilizar no Group by, o campo deve ser listado também no SELECT.

```
 select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, SUM(ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE) as Quantidade, CLIENTE.NOME from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido
 GROUP BY ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, CLIENTE.NOME
```

Nome que há necessidade de adicionar na cláusula GROUP BY, todos os campos  presentes na cláusula SELECT que não sejam funções de agregação.

[AGRUPAR POR (Entity SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/group-by-entity-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você for fazer a somatória em uma consulta você precisa definir quais são os itens que pretende somar

no seu caso você pode utilizar a soma para quantidade e agrupar por cliente e pedido a consulta ficará assim:

```
select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO,  CLIENTE.NOME sum (ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE) qte
from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido
group by ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO,  CLIENTE.NOME
```

Como não conheço sua tabela direito, não tenho como informar o relacinamento para eliminar duplicatas

Comment: Favor não utilizar este site para fazer propaganda.

Comment: Estou usando o oracle live SQL

Amigo tentei usar o seu codigo da seguinte forma:
select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, CLIENTE.NOME sum (ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE) qte 
from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido 
where PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO=ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO AND CLIENTE.IDCLIENTE = PEDIDO.IDCLIENTE
group by ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, CLIENTE.NOME order by ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE

segue o seguinte erro
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: precisava que você me manda-se os select das 3 tabelas que está utilizando, assim consingo montar o select que você precisa, se quiser pode me mandar no meu email chinarelliti@fpw.com.br

Answer (score 0):

Falta acrescentar no `GROUP BY`, a coluna `CLIENTE.NOME`

Ficaria assim:

```
select ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, sum (ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE), CLIENTE.NOME  from ITEMPEDIDO, cliente, pedido
 where PEDIDO.IDPEDIDO=ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO AND CLIENTE.IDCLIENTE = PEDIDO.IDCLIENTE
 group by ITEMPEDIDO.IDPEDIDO, CLIENTE.NOME
 order by ITEMPEDIDO.QUANTIDADE desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola consegui solucionar da seguinte forma

select  cliente.nome, sum(itempedido.quantidade) "Total compra" from itempedido
inner join  pedido on pedido.idpedido = itempedido.idpedido
inner join cliente on cliente.idcliente = pedido.idpedido

```
group by pedido.idpedido, cliente.nome
order by sum(itempedido.quantidade) desc 

FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```